# Data Fixtures many to one self referencing

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I used DoctrineFixturesBundle to fill my db for 50000 records.I want to have many employee to one boss. But now when I filled my db I have in boss_id only null values
My load function:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {

        for ($i = 0; $i <= 50000; $i++) {
            $employee = new Employee();
            if($i == 0) {
                $employee->setPosition('founder');
            }
            $employee->setFullName('new employee'.$i);
            $employee->setSalary(50000 - $i);
            $employee->setStartDate(new \DateTime());
            if($i > 0) {
                $employee->setBoss($manager->find(Employee::class,1));
                $employee->setPosition('boss');
            } elseif ($i >= 1000) {
                $id = rand(2,1000);
                $employee->setBoss($manager->find(Employee::class,$id));
                $employee->setPosition('top-manager');
            } elseif ($i >= 5000) {
                $id = rand (1000,4999);
                $employee->setBoss($manager->find(Employee::class,$id));
                $employee->setPosition('manager');
            } elseif ($i >= 10000){
                $id = rand(5000,9999);
                $employee->setBoss($manager->find(Employee::class,$id));
                $employee->setPosition('worker');
            }
            $manager->persist($employee);

        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
```

My Entity Employee:

```
 /**
     * @var Employee
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Employee")
     */
    private $boss;
public function setBoss(\AppBundle\Entity\Employee $boss = null)
    {
        $this->boss = $boss;

        return $this;
    }
```

how can I do this trick? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your object is not created when you use it

use the `addReference`as explained in [the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)